# Push to nested array in React Native and to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add an array inside of array to firebase(hope its the right defenition)

**This is the State im using to hold and then eventually push its content into Firebase:**

```
  const [monts, setMonts] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Jan", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 2, name: "Feb", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 3, name: "Mar", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 4, name: "Apr", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 5, name: "May", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 6, name: "Jun", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 7, name: "Jul", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 8, name: "Aug", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 9, name: "Sep", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 10, name: "Oct", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 11, name: "Nov", check: false, days: [] },
    { id: 12, name: "Dec", check: false, days: [] },
  ]);
```

**This is my code for pushing the dates into Firebase - 100% Working**

```
 const curYear = new Date();
    var firstDay = new Date(curYear.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    const lastDayInMonth = new Date(curYear.getFullYear(), 1, 1);


    const forma = new Date();
    const startTime = "08:00";
    let i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (
          firstDay;
          firstDay < lastDayInMonth;
          firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1)
        ) {
          if (firstDay < lastDayInMonth){
            const formatDate = new Date(firstDay);
            moment.locale("he");
            monts[i].days.push(moment(formatDate).format("L"));
          } 
        }
        lastDayInMonth.setMonth(lastDayInMonth.getMonth() + 1); 
    }

    monts.forEach((item) => {
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(uid)
          .collection("aviailablty")
          .doc(item.name)
          .set({ item });
    });
  }
```

And this is the outcome in firebase:
[image: Firebase]

**Red Marker -> i want to add here inside the value of the Date(1/1/2020 for instance) another 3 variables that will create this build:**
01/01/2020
startTime: ""
endTime: ""
status: ""

all of this as one , how can i do it???

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish.  Please edit the question to show the desired outcome, along with code that you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Hey Doug,
what im trying to accomplish is to add to the Date in Firebase(see the image) another params,
Meaning: as you can see the "days" is expendable and hold the dates of the month
im trying to add to every date another params, so the date will hold data too

Comment: So all you want to do is add another string to the `days` list?  If that's not it, I suggest showing a screenshot or describing in more detail what the updated document should look like.